# Count the number of contiguous empty cells at the end of a row

Tags: openoffice, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I have rows of data, some cells are empty and some contain a number. I need to identify how many contiguous empty cells exist at the end of each row.

I've tried using a string of nested IF statements, but there are often 15-20 empty cells and I don't think that I can have 20 nested IF statements (?).

for example: _ _ 1 2 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 1 1 _ _ _ _ (underscore represents a blank cell) For this row, there a 4 empty cells at the end of the row. I need to count empty cells (backwards from the end of the row) and then stop when a non-empty cell is reached.

Can anyone help?

Comment: COUNTBLANK or SUMPRODUCT(TRIM(CLEAN(bla1:Bla2))="") at the end of the rows?

Comment: Hi Blomkvist, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately this counts every individual empty cell in the entire row... I am trying to find out how many contiguous blank cells exist at the end of a row... for example:
_ _ 1 2 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 1 1 _ _ _ _   (underscore represents a blank cell)
For this row, there a 4 empty cells at the end of the row. I need to count empty cells (backwards from the end of the row) and then stop when a non-empty cell is reached.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while so I'm hoping a LibreOffice solution may be better than nothing:

[image: SU279758 example]